# Debugging an sbt build that doesn't see any tests

Tags: scala, sbt

The context:

- sbt 0.13.0, Scala 2.10.4
- I need a custom directory structure because of external constraints, so I added all my test sources to my sbt project with `scalaSource in Test := baseDirectory.value / "test"`
- `test:compile` picks up all my test sources and compiles them successfully (I can add syntax errors and cause the build to fail)
- `test` reports that there are 0 suites, 0 tests, and that all succeeded
- I have several junit-style scalatest tests in that directory

Any ideas why it's not picking up any tests? Is there a setting I missed? `show definedTests` also shows an empty list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I was missing a dependency on `junit-interface`:

`libraryDependencies += "com.novocode" % "junit-interface" % "0.8" % Test`